# React "base class"/ inheritance

Tags: reactjs

I'm pretty new to React,
And I was given a simple home assignment.

I was asked to create 3 kinds of a clickable circle component.

The JSX is common to all (SVG),
But their

- size
- background color
- onClick callback

are different.

What is the correct way **nowadays** (2019, React 16) to get such a common base class/
interface in React ?

HOC ? React Hooks ? some other way ?

Say this is my "base" Circle component
(Please ignore the hard coded props):

```
export default function Circle(props) {
  return (
    <svg height="100" width="100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="26" fill="#9cc6d4" />
      <circle
        cx="50"
        cy="50"
        r="20"
        stroke="#FFF"
        strokeWidth="1"
        fill="none"
      />
    </svg>
  );
```

I want to make myself clear:

***I've only 3 different types of that basic Circle***
(Say Red, Blue and Yellow...)
And I need to put them on screen according
to a JSON.

I don't want to DRY and create
3 different classes: RedCircle, BlueCircle and YellowCircle...
which eventually will be based on the same JSX

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a requirement to use class?

Comment: @Rajasekar There are no requirements, I just want to know what in your opinion is the best **professional** way to achieve it. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do these cutomizations with props..

```
   const {size, onClick, bgColor} = props;
   // now use the size, onClick and bgColor props in your JSX markup
  return (
    <svg height="100" width="100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="26" fill="#9cc6d4" />
      <circle
        cx="50"
        cy="50"
        r="20"
        stroke="#FFF"
        strokeWidth="1"
        fill="none"
      />
    </svg>
  );
```

Using the Circle component would look like

```
<Circle size={'40'} onClick={()=>{ console.log('im red circle'}) bgColor={'red'} />
<Circle size={'35'} onClick={()=>{ console.log('im green circle'}) bgColor={'green'} />
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html 
Please also read this for better understanding why inheritance is not a preferred way to make dynamic components

Answer (score 0):

You can pass these infos, by using the `props` parameter of the function component.

Your component would look something like that:

```
export default function Circle(props) {
 return (
 <svg height={props.size} width={props.size}>
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="26" fill={props.color} />
   <circle
     cx="50"
     cy="50"
     r="20"
     stroke="#FFF"
     strokeWidth="1"
     fill="none"
  />
 </svg>
 );
}
```

Then, when used in parent components:

```
 <Circle size={yourSize} color={yourColor}/>
```

In this case, `size` etc... would be available in the function as `props.size` etc...

You can do the same and pass event handlers like onClick etc...

Reference:
https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html